# Почему не работает theme_preprocess_menu_link?

Tags: php, drupal

Требуется сделать так, чтобы в теме Drupal 7 подсвечивался активный пункт меню, для этого нужно задать класс `active` тегу `<li>` вместо `<a>`. По определёным причинам CSS я менять не могу.
Пытаюсь это сделать с помощью `theme_preprocess_menu_link()`:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_menu_link (&$variables) {
$element = $variables['element'];
$attributes = $element['#attributes'];
$attributes['class'] = array_unique($attributes['class']);
$classes = $attributes['class'];
if (in_array('active-trail', $classes) || ($element['#href'] == '<front>' && drupal_is_front_page())) {
  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'active';
  }
}

function mytheme_menu_link__main_menu ($variables) {
$element = $variables['element'];
$sub_menu = '';

if ($element['#below']) {
  $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
$output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href']);
return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

Результата нет - по прежнему данный класс устанавливается только тегу `a`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить класс правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась присваиванием `$element` ссылки:

```
$element = &$variables['element'];
```